# Cannot type a certain key on Mac Mini keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard

I am using an Apple Mac Mini.  Today something changed and now I can't type any longer the letter `p` or `P`.

If I type `s` it writes `ds`.  Did I hit some unknown combination?

Comment: Have you tried switching keyboards, to make sure its the mac mini and not your keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a stuck/broken key. Try plugging the keyboard into another computer - if the key works there, it's the Mac, but I find that quite unlikely. If it's the keyboard, take it to an Apple Store for a replacement.